# how to add a tool bar with back and fourth button programmatically in a webview to navigate in iphone?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I have an application in which i need a navigation through the wepages in webview.can anybody give me suggessions on how to add a toolbar with navigation on to the weview in iphone like the twitter app[image]

Comment: U mean the UI or the Functionality?

Comment: i mean is there any inbuilt mechanism for it or i need to create one toolbar?

Comment: there is none..`[myWebView goBack] `and `[myWebView goForward]` are to be actions of back and forward button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use next open source class [Browser View Controller](https://github.com/tonisalae/TSMiniWebBrowser)

```
TSMiniWebBrowser *webBrowser = [[TSMiniWebBrowser alloc] initWithUrl:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://indiedevstories.com"]];

[self.navigationController pushViewController:webBrowser animated:YES];
```

[image: TSMiniWebBrowser]

Answer (score 0):

You can add segment control on you navigation bar....

```
  - (IBAction)segment_control_index_changed:(id)sender {

switch (self.segment_control.selectedSegmentIndex) {

    case 0:

        if (self._webview.canGoBack) {
            [self._webview goBack];
        }

        break;

    case 1:

        if (self._webview.canGoForward) {
            [self._webview goForward];
        }

        break;

        case 2:




        break;

    default:

        break;

}
```

}